# Почему margin'ы наезжают друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

Привет, коллеги!

Уже давно знаю о такой штуке, что если два блока (один под другим) и у обоих будет `margin: 9px 0`, например то общее расстояние между ними составит 9px, а не 18. Почему так, и можно ли с этим бороться?

P.S. Наглядно тут: http://jsfiddle.net/ubpeK/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Здесь](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/margin-collapsing-trick.html)** все подробно описано.

Answer (score 0):

а если так http://jsfiddle.net/ubpeK/3/

Comment: Зачем такие извращения?